# Why WrappedMonad and WrappedArrow?

Tags: haskell, applicative, newtype

Why does the `WrappedMonad` and `WrappedArrow` types exist? Is it because `Monad`s were not `Applicative`? Given that `WrappedArrow` exists, should the instance

```
Arrow a => Applicative (Arrow a b)
```

simply be built into the Haskell itself the same way that `Applicative` is now a superclass of `Monad`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much so for `WrappedMonad`. I guess it is becoming (and perhaps already was) essentially obsolete. But `WrappedArrow` is more difficult, because `Arrow` types and `Applicative` types have different kinds, `* -> * -> *` vs. `* -> *`.  And because of the way GHC instance resolution works, adding the instance (I assume the extra `Arrow` was a typo)

```
instance Arrow a => Applicative (a b)
```

would mean that *no* type constructor with two or more arguments could then give an `Applicative` without also giving an `Arrow` - that seems rather drastic.

The reverse option of adding a superclass `Applicative (a b) =>` to `Arrow a` would seem more palatable - except you cannot have superclasses with a forall'ed type like `b`.  Such superclasses would be useful for other things as well, and have been suggested many times, so I assume it is hard to implement well.

Comment: It's also the case that most people consider the `Arrow` class to be designed wrong, so making it a superclass of the extremely important `Applicative` class would probably not go over so well.

Comment: @dfeuer subclass, not superclass. It wouldn't affect `Applicative` directly. Still, not possible with the current class system.

Answer (score 1):

I feel [the `DerivingVia` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-via) gives a new lease of life to this kind of newtype wrapper. Let's suppose that, for whatever reason, we want to write `Monad` and `MonadPlus` instances for a type and then piggyback on them for `Applicative` and `Alternative`:

```
newtype StT s m a = StT { runStT :: s -> m (a, s) }
    deriving Functor

instance Monad m => Monad (StT s m) where
    return a = StT $ \s -> return (a, s)
    m >>= f = StT $ \s -> m `runStT` s >>= \(a, t) -> f a `runStT` t

instance MonadPlus m => MonadPlus (StT s m) where
    mzero = StT $ \_ -> mzero
    m `mplus` n = StT $ \s -> (m `runStT` s) `mplus` (n `runStT` s)
```

Ordinarily, we'd have to write boilerplate instances:

```
instance Monad m => Applicative (StT s m) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance MonadPlus m => Alternative (StT s m) where
    empty = mzero
    (<|>) = mplus
```

With `DerivingVia`, `WrappedMonad` can be used to spell it out in a way that, to my eyes, is much nicer.

```
newtype StT s m a = StT { runStT :: s -> m (a, s) }
    deriving Functor
    deriving (Applicative, Alternative) via WrappedMonad (StT s m)
```

Note that preexisting deriving clauses are unaffected. Another nice touch is that the necessary superclass constraints are inferred.